# Is there any way to get customer duplicate data from customers table then update all others except 1 row from duplicate data?

Tags: oracle19c

I am trying to get duplicate data of my customers table then after finding update isactive column of all duplicates found to 0 except 1 row of the duplicate data.

here is my script using oracle 19c:

```
merge into customers c
using (
        WITH cte AS (
          SELECT DISTINCT ROWID, fn_createfullname(firstname, middlename, lastname) as fullName, mobile, branchid, isactive,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fn_createfullname(firstname, middlename, lastname), mobile, branchid ORDER BY ROWID) AS rn
          FROM customers
        )   
        select * from cte
        WHERE rn > 1
    ) tbl
    on (tbl.mobile = c.mobile and fn_createfullname(c.firstname, c.middlename, c.lastname) = tbl.fullname)
    when matched then update
    SET c.isactive = 0
    WHERE rn > 1;
```

i am expecting to get all duplicate data then update single row from duplicate data.

plz any help.

after running my query is displaying this error:

> Error report - ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the
> source tables

Comment: Are there any data updates running at the same time? This error usually means you should try again.

Comment: What is the PK of your customer table?